# How to list a record with 5th largest value without $ArraySort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection:

```
{
  _id: ... ,
  userId: ...,
  gadgets: 3
}
```

I need to find all users who have at least 5 records in the collection. For every such user, I then need to sort the number of gadgets in descending order and get the 5th value. And, I am still at mongodb 4.4 and so, can't do `$sortArray`.

For example, if user has records with 14, 10, 7, 7, 5 gadgets (in any order), result should be:

```
{
   userId: ....
   qualifyingGadgets: 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a MongoDB server at version 4.4 to test, but I think you'll have all these aggregation operations available.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "gadgets": {"$push": "$gadgets"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gte": [{"$size": "$gadgets"}, 5]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$gadgets"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {"gadgets": -1}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "gadgets": {"$push": "$gadgets"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "userId": "$_id",
      "qualifyingGadgets": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$gadgets", 4]}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZhWF1XpDNWa).

Comment: Brilliant @rickhg12hs! I knew I needed to unwind and sort, but I thought I needed to sort by user AND gadgets, which I obviously don't have to, as you've shown.

Comment: Shortened it a bit to remove the first 3 stages: group, match and unwind. Added a match for `$exists: true` at the end. This can slow it down a bit, but I can live with that. The answer is perfect, generally speaking.

Comment: @IrinaRapoport I thought about doing that too, but I'm not sure how many docs are in the collection and I thought getting to a `"$match"` stage as soon as possible might help.  Overall, the query won't be that performant, but if it doesn't need to run often and the runtime is acceptable, then I too "can live with that".  You might consider adding your pipeline as another answer for others to see.